# Special cases of distributions

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, skewness, t-distribution

I'm confused on the special cases for some distributions and i'm looking for some clarity.

I know that the standard normal distribution is a special case of the normal distribution with a mean of 0, standard deviation of 1 and that the skewness and kurtosis of any normal distribution is 0 and 3 respectively.

What i'm looking for is this case for these distributions:

T distribution, Skewed-t distribution, skewed normal distribution.

By 'this case' I don't mean the standard normal distribution for these distributions. I'm just looking for what would be the equivalent special case relative to the distribution.

Edit: Another question I have is specifically for the student-t distribution. What would be the specific case for it and what values would its parameters have?

Comment: I think t-dist converges to the normal distribution so it's not a special case of normal.

Comment: It's unclear the sense in which you mean "the equivalent case" -- what specifically are you seeking?

Comment: "Standard normal" is not the "special case" of normal distribution, but it is a *name* of normal distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$, the same as "standard uniform" is the *name* used to denote the $U(0,1)$ distribution. It is not clear what do you mean by "special case" of a distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b I think I may have confused myself with the relationship of the normal distribution and the standard normal distribution. By equivalent case I meant this: N(μ,σ^2) is the normal distribution. N(0,1) is the standard normal distribution when you set the values of the parameters. So my question was, is there a specific case (by that I mean popular) where the parameters of the t distribution are set to a certain value. But this was cleared up by Peter Flom as he mentioned the only parameter is the DOF.

Comment: @Tim I see. So what would be the relationship of the t distribution to the student-t distribution?

Comment: @HumzaAli it's the same distribution... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree somewhat with Peter's characterization of the situation with the t-distribution, so I'll outline where I'd put it differently  (this started as a comment but got too long with all the links).

The t-distribution that's in t-tables (e.g. see the [wikipedia page on the distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution)) - that you'd use for tests and CIs and so on - is "standard" in the sense that is has location parameter 0 and scale parameter 1. (The variables used for those calculations get standardized.)

You can also have [a location-scale family]((e.g. see the [wikipedia page on the distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) for the t-distribution. That corresponds to the general normal (not that for the t-distribution, the scale parameter $\sigma$ is not the standard deviation, however). This is the version that's needed when modelling data.

[You might find the Wikipedia article on [location-scale families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-scale_family) useful background]

---

Moments of the t-distribution; this information is readily obtained from the wikipedia article on it:

The mean and variance of the t-distribution in terms of the parameters are given by $\mu$ and $\sigma^2 \frac{\nu}{\nu-2}$; the skewness and kurtosis are $0$ and $3+\frac{6}{\nu-4}$.

However, matching the sample kurtosis is not generally a suitable way to choose a $t$-distribution for modelling data.

Further, simply comparing sample skewness and kurtosis to population skewness and kurtosis -- no matter how close they are -- doesn't tell you that you have a suitable model. e.g. even if your sample skewness is 0 and sample kurtosis is 3, it *doesn't* imply a normal distribution is a good model, and it doesn't imply that assuming a normal distribution won't lead to any problems; the issue can be even worse with the $t$ (where the sample kurtosis in particular can be quite  biased and *very* noisy)

Comment: I see. So the Non-standardized Student's t-distribution is what I've used to model my data with. Just a few follow up questions: I'm writing a dissertation on modelling skewness and kurtosis for stock returns. So basically I have to look at the normal distribution and use skewness and kurtosis to suggest if the normal distribution is a good model or not. I then have to look at other distributions and since the student-t distribution is less prone to heavy tails I use it next.

Comment: For the Normal distribution I derived the moments using mgf and obviously found out skewness is 0 and kurtosis is 3. I then found out the skewness and kurtosis of my data and compared it to these values. This wasn't the only thing I did but I'm wondering if I can do something similar with the t-distribution? So far I've used the stdFit(MYDATA) on 'R' to find the parameters of the student-t distribution but now i've realised thats got nothing to do with the moments...

Comment: I've added some information to my answer. If you need more than that you should probably ask a new question (though much of this is covered in answers already on site - a few good searches may be a goo didea)

Answer (score 5):

I think the reason you are confused is that there really is no equivalent.

The "standard normal" is used and is useful for two reasons. First, the normal is very very common.  Second, in the old days when we had to look up values in tables, we needed to make the Normal distribution have one table. So, they picked a mean of 0 and sd of 1, somewhat arbitrarily, and people converted other normals to that.

The t distribution is, in a way, automatically standardized (the unstandardized version is the [noncentral t distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution)).  That is, it doesn't have parameters for mean and variance, only for degrees of freedom. There is no way to make a equivalent standard for degrees of freedom. The t *is* the special case, but it is a whole bunch of cases, because df varies.

The skew normal has 3 parameters (for shape, scale and location) and the standard normal is a special case of this distribution.

Comment: This answer confuses standardization with noncentrality.  The two concepts differ substantially.  One *can* standardize t-distributions (and this shows up sometimes in the literature) by rescaling them to have specified variances (for df greater than $2$) or specified IQRs, say (for any df).  Because all are symmetric around zero, there is no need to *shift* their locations.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I understand now what confused me. Just a quick follow up question:

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "doesn't have parameters for mean and variance"

For example, I wanted to plot the best t-distribution curve on a histogram for my data. To do this I had to estimate the mean, standard deviation and dof. So that means I'm using an unstandardized version?

Thank you

Comment: @whuber  I only used "standardized" to mesh with the OP's usage. It does get confusing! I am not sure how to word this better.

Comment: The t distribution has a parameter for df, but not for mean or variance, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution. The mean and variance are set by the df (same site)

Comment: "Standardization" as described in the question makes sense only within a location-scale family.  Since there is a natural way to extend any family that is not a location-scale family to be one, you may consider a "three-parameter Student t" distribution to be given by df, location, and scale.  That still has nothing to do with the noncentrality parameter, which is irrelevant.  (It's a shape parameter.)